# optional textfields in a form end up as undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I've optional textfields in a form, once submitted and they are empty then they end up as undefined in my database.

I'm trying to find a quick way so I don't have to go each field and check if it's undefined and set an empty space `""` to it, because I've several fields and several forms.

```
this.$scope.data = {};


   submit: function() {
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append("name", this.$scope.data.name);
        formData.append("title", this.$scope.data.title);
        formData.append("company", this.$scope.data.company);
```

Related html

```
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Speaker Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" ng-model="data.name" required />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3">Title</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control" ng-model="data.title" />
```

Comment: Showing some code could help a lot.

Comment: I think using `$scope.data.name` is a bad idea, it should be `$scope.name` only

Comment: nops, still the same issue, getting rid of $scope.data = {}, setting $scope.name has the same problem as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
formData.append("name", this.$scope.data.name || 'default');
```

Comment: yes, this is what I'm doing, what if I've lots of forms and fields?

Comment: You can initialise the variables in the controller, from one central location. That's enough to have a default value for the fields. No need to set "value" either. I think this is the best/most Angular way.